# How to go to the second found word in TextView | ANDROID

Tags: android, search, textview, getline

I have the following problem:

The code below is a method to search, mark and go to the first found word in the TextView which is entered in the Edittext.

**Does anyone know how to go to the second found word in case of entering the search button again and how to mark it?**

```
String textToFind = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();

SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(fullTxt);

final int index = fullTxt.indexOf(textToFind);
if(index == -1) {
    // text does not contain the word
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text '" + textToFind + "' not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else {
    int lineNum = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(index);
    int lineStart = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineNum -1);
    int lineEnd = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineNum);
    // set style to the entire line, as your origional code
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#035525")), lineStart, lineEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), lineStart, lineEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(spannable);
    textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int line = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(index);
            int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(line);
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, y);
        }
    });
}
```

THANKS for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought of a potential solution, using similar method you have at the moment.  If knowing the length of the string and its starting and ending position.  You could have a copy of the full text where you keep a split from the ending position of the last word found.  This way you can keep doing indexof on the remaining string and keep going until ending.

Or potentially another method is having an array of its characters and attempting to find a order of characters found.  Such as

```
for int i = 0; i < fulltext.length; i++; {
    if fulltext[i] == textToFind[0] && fulltext[i+1] == textToFind[1] ....{
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I try this later :)